# Gradle task that depends on other task output?

Tags: gradle

I have a custom task that depends on `installDist` - not only for execution, but also on `installDist` output:

```
project.task('run', type: JavaExec, dependsOn: 'installDist', overwrite: true) {
    def libdir = new File("$project.tasks.installDist.destinationDir/lib")
    ...
```

It happens that when running the first time, the `libdir` does not catch the destination dir of `installDist`, because of how the Gradle works. Since I need to use `libdir` for my task, how can I wait for the installDist to finish, and then to run my task?

I know I can explicitly run `installDist` before my task, but I want just to run my task after `clean` up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After @Ben Greens answer, I figured:

```
project.task('run', type: JavaExec, dependsOn: 'installDist', overwrite: true) {
    doFirst {
        def libdir = new File("$project.tasks.installDist.destinationDir/lib")
...
```

so this happens before my task is executed, but after the `installDist` is executed.

Answer (score 2):

The task lifecycle is a little confusing. Gradle reads through the whole file and tries to configure the tasks before actually executing them. Take a look at the build.gradle in Example 20.1 on https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_lifecycle.html for more info on the lifecycle.

To avoid this, you could try putting the relevent task info into a `doLast` block like so:

```
task run() {
    dependsOn 'installDist'
    doLast {
        javaexec {
            main = project.mainClassName
            classpath = project.configurations.standaloneRuntime
            def libdir = new File("$project.tasks.installDist.destinationDir/lib")
        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually `doFirst` was the solution. I knew for doLast, but that wont work as i need to use lib dir before the task is executed, not after. Can you update the comment so i can mark it

Comment: @игор Ahh ok, so did you just call the installDist in your doFirst?

Comment: No, just used doFirst over the `def libdir` block. Without explicit call to javaexec

Comment: @игор Ahh ok. Well as I didn't actually help, I shouldn't take any credit for it. Put your own answer explaining the answer, and I will upvote it :)

Comment: no worries, just to have an answer that worked, for other ppl. thank you!